# Getting 403 error while making a youtube analytics api call

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I have access to the channel and it is happening only for some videos in the channel. any idea what may be the reason ??

> [com.spr.channel.error.AccessForbiddenException: Exception while
>   processing request for accountId: 37393 Channel Type: YOUTUBE Message:
>   403 Forbidden
>
> ```
> {
>   "code" : 403,
>   "errors" : [ {
>     "domain" : "global",
>     "message" : "Forbidden",
>     "reason" : "forbidden"
>   } ],
>   "message" : "Forbidden"
> }
> ```
>
> at com.spr.channel.error.translator.GPlusExceptionTranslator.doTranslateException(GPlusExceptionTranslator.java:72)
>     at
>   com.spr.channel.error.translator.AbstractChannelApiExceptionTranslator.translateException(AbstractChannelApiExceptionTranslator.java:42)
>     at
>   com.spr.channel.sn.youtube.YouTubeV3APIClientImpl.translateException(YouTubeV3APIClientImpl.java:952)
>     at
>   com.spr.channel.sn.youtube.YouTubeV3APIClientImpl.executeQuery(YouTubeV3APIClientImpl.java:154)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor140.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: i am makinh a call to analytics api for getting data of this video.

Comment: Can you post an example `videoId` where you get this error?

Comment: What data/operation are you trying to access and who are you authorized as when you're making the request? Can you post some code?

Comment: Also just fyi, you can find a list of error codes [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors). If you haven't already, I'd also recommend checking out the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/)